# How to define a JSON array with concrete item definition for every index (i.e. a tuple) in OpenAPI?

Tags: tuples, openapi

I need to define in OpenAPI a JSON response with an array. The array always contains 2 items and the first one is always a number and second one is always a string.

```
[1, "a"]    //valid
["a", 1]    //invalid
[1]         //invalid
[1, "a", 2] //invalid
```

I've found out that JSON schema does support that by passing a list of items in `items` instead of single object ([source](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html)), but OpenAPI explicitly forbids that and accepts only a single object ([source](http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.2#schema-object)). How can that be expressed in OpenAPI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need OpenAPI 3.1 to define tuples precisely. In earlier versions, you can only define generic arrays without a specific item order.

#### OpenAPI 3.1

Your example can be defined as:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

type: array
prefixItems:
  # The 1st item
  - type: integer
    description: Description of the 1st item
  # The 2nd item
  - type: string
    description: Description of the 2nd item
  # Define the 3rd etc. items if needed
  # ...

# The total number of items in this tuple
minItems: 2
maxItems: 2
additionalItems: false   # can be omitted if `maxItems` is specified
```

OpenAPI 3.1 is fully compatible with JSON Schema 2020-12, including the `prefixItems` keyword (the new name for the [tuple form of `items`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation) from earlier JSON Schema drafts).

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x and earlier

Earlier OpenAPI versions do not have a way to describe tuples. The most you can do is define "an array of 2 items that can be either number or string", but you cannot specifically define the type of the 1st and 2nd items. You can, however, mention additional constraints in the schema `description`.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.0

type: array
items:
  oneOf:
    - type: integer
    - type: string
minItems: 2
maxItems: 2
description: >-
  The first item in the array MUST be an integer,
  and the second item MUST be a string.
```

If you are designing a new API rather than describing an existing one, a possible workaround is to use an object instead of an array to represent this data structure.