# YAML/OpenAPI: Define key value pair with value having two fields in value (integer and string)

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, openapi

While creating OpenAPI 3.0 I need to define a key value pair with value having two fields, first integer and second string like: `user: priority, status` (e.g. `'user1': 3, 'available'`). How can I combine two primitive data types for the value? How can I define it's schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a JSON array with concrete item definition for every index (i.e. a tuple) in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464633/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a key-value pair, you can use the `"additionalProperties"` keyword:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "priority": "{"type": "integer"},
      "status": {"type": "string"}
    }
  }
}
```

This means that the root value should be an object, with no defined properties in `"properties"`. But every property value, that isn't defined in `"properties"`, should be an object with the two properties you need.

The relevant section of the json schema spec: [additionalProperties](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#additionalProperties)