# How to define an OpenAPI ordered array of different objects?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to define my API using OpenAPI version 3.0. I am trying to generate a YAML file which has four maps, and each map contains a different information. How can I create a YAML file to achieve that goal? I know that my components are not right because of which I am not getting the right result.

Request body should be like this:

```
[
  UserInformation{FirstName, LastName},
  AddressInformation{Phone, Address},
  ContactInformation{Email, Phone}
]
```

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: 'INPUT-FORM-API'

paths:
  /api/v1/test/healthcheck:
    get:
      summary: Health check for the test api services. Used Internally
      operationId: Externalhealthcheck
      description: healthcheck for the test services status.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: This status is always returned when service is Ok.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HealthcheckObject'

  /api/v1/test/newformentry:
    post:
      summary: End Point to insert data into the new table.
      operationId: NewFormEntry
      description: EndPoint to insert data for new form.
      requestBody:
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewFormEntry'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: This status is always returned when service is Ok.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HealthcheckObject'

components:
  schemas:
    NewFormEntry:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserInformation'
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/AddressInformation'
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ContactInformation'
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MessageFromBene'
    UserInformation:
      required:
        - FirstName
        - LastName
      properties:
        FirstName:
          type: string
        LastName:
          type: string
          
    AddressInformation:
      required:
        - StreetAddress
        - City
        - State
        - ZipCode
      properties:
        StreetAddress:
          type: string
        StreetAddress2:
          type: string
        City:
          type: string
        State:
          type: string  
        ZipCode:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          
    ContactInformation:
      required:
        - PhoneNumber
        - Email
      properties:
        PhoneNumber:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          maximum: 9
        Email:
          type: string
        HomePhone:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          maximum: 9
        Cell:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          maximum: 9
        WorkPhone:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          maximum: 9
    
    MessageFromBene:
      required:
        - Message
      properties:
        PhoneNumber:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          maximum: 9
        Message:
          type: string
    
    HealthcheckObject:
      required:
        - Status
        - ErrorMessage
      properties:
        Status:
          type: string
        ErrorMessage:
          type: string
```

Comment: `NewFormEntry` definition is incorrect. What is that object supposed to be? E.g. a merger of `UserInformation`, `AddressInformation` and other objects into one; or _one_ of these objects; or something else?

Comment: It should be an array of these objects. Request should be
[ {First Name, Last Name},
{Phone Number, Address, Email}] @Helen

Answer (score 1):

So the `NewFormEntry` schema must be an array containing 3 objects, where the 1st object must be `UserInformation`, the second object must be `AddressInformation`, and the 3rd object  mube be `ContactInformation`. This is like a [*tuple*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464633/113116), i.e. an ordered sequence of elements where each element has a specfic type. Tuple definitions are slightly different in different OpenAPI versions.

#### OpenAPI 3.1

If or when you migrate to OAS 3.1, such an array can be defined using [`prefixItems`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation). This keyword specifies the schema for each element position (in other words, it specifies the *order* of elements in the array):

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    NewFormEntry:
      type: array
      prefixItems:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserInformation'    # type of the 1st element
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AddressInformation' # type of the 2nd element
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ContactInformation' # type of the 3rd element
      minItems: 3
      maxItems: 3
      additionalItems: false   # can be omitted if `maxItems: 3` is specified
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0

In OAS 3.0, you can define the array length (i.e. 3 items) and the possible types of array items (i.e. each item can be either `A`, `B`, or `C`), but there's no way to define a specific order of objects in the array. So the most you can do is this:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    NewFormEntry:
      type: array
      items:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserInformation'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AddressInformation'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ContactInformation'
      minItems: 3
      maxItems: 3
```

Note that this definition allows arbitrary order of objects in the array and also multiple instances of the same object (e.g. `[UserInformation, UserInformation, UserInformation]`). You might want to implement additional backend validations to verify the desired order of objects in this array.