# How to define positional arguments in OpenAPI for POST body?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to create an OpenAPI description for an existing API. That API expects positional parameters in an array in the post body.

For example:

```
POST /example

[
  "first parameter",
  7,
  [1,2,4,5]
]
```

What's the correct way to define that? My idea was something along the lines of:

```json
"requestBody": {
  "required": true,
  "content": {
    "application\/json": {
      "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that's obviously wrong. What's the correct way?

Comment: Depending on the version of OAS, you have different/limited options.  It's documented well in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109952/8564731

in JSON Schema draft-04, your question has the proper syntax, but the OpenAPI Spec diverged from JSON Schema in v3.0.x and eventually returned to support full JSON Schema 2020-12 in OAS v3.1.0 but the syntax has changed to use `prefixItems` i/o `items[]`

Comment: @JeremyFiel okay I can use 3.1.0 and using prefixItem seems to work (at least I'm not getting errors) but loading the spec in https://editor-next.swagger.io/ still doesn't create a proper description of the body. Any chance you could create a working example for my given usecase above?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an OAS 3.1.0 version of positional arguments. It seems like the Swagger editor-next is having some issue with the requestBody $ref but it also seems to resolve it successfully. Not sure, I don't use swagger at all. We use Redocly.

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.1.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "stack",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "https://www.host.com"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/thing": {
            "post": {
                "description": "a post request with positional arguments",
                "requestBody": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/post_request"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "201": {
                        "description": "Created",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "requestBodies": {
            "post_request": {
                "description": "a post request with positional arguments",
                "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "prefixItems": [
                                {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "minimum": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "minimum": 0
                                    },
                                    "unevaluatedItems": false
                                }
                            ],
                            "unevaluatedItems": false
                        },
                        "examples": {
                            "post_request": {
                                "summary": "an example of positional arguments",
                                "value": [
                                        "test",
                                         1000,
                                         [123, 456, 789]
                                    ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: redocly]

[image: swagger]

Comment: I thought this would be the answer, but it seems even though it doesn't throw any errors, and is somewhat sensibly displayed in the swagger editor, it is not really supported when generating API clients based on the spec. To me it seems neither OpenAPI nor JSON-Schema really support the concept of something Python would probably call a Tuple - a fixed list of values of different types, identified by order.

Comment: This is the only way to define a tuple like structure with JSON Schema or OpenAPI.  You may be having a language specific issue with the type defined in the python json library. I'm not familiar with python, but this may give you some insight into your issue. https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array

Comment: you didn't indicate the python implementation used. but this reference from pydantic and fastapi gives a decent overview  https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/3210

Comment: I'm not using Python, it's just that Python has actually a concept for this type of array. Meanwhile I found the JSON schema docs on prefixItems, which incidentally calls it TupleValidation: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array#tupleValidation So yeah I guess JSON schema supports it, it is valid in OA 3.1, but none of the API client generator tools properly support it