# How to define a nested array in OpenAPI?

Tags: yaml, openapi

I want to define this

```json
     "locationPoly": [
          [-87.63466, 24.50182],
          [-80.03074, 24.50182],
          [-80.03074, 31.00107],
          [-87.63466, 31.00107],
          [-87.63466, 24.50182]
        ],
```

In my OpenAPI YAML schema, I defined it like this:

```yaml
                  locationPoly:
                    type: array
                    properties:
                      type: array
                      properties:
                        type: number
```

But I am getting the "schema is invalid" error. Is there another way to define this?

Answer (score 3):

**Arrays must use the `items` keyword.**

```
locationPoly:
  type: array
  items:
    type: array
    items:
      type: number
```

Comment: Per @Helen 's idea, If the inner arrays always contain 2 elements, you can add `minItems: 2` and `maxItems: 2` for documentation purposes. Though IMO, if you're going to begin to define criteria like that, it's better to explicitly define an object schema that can be reusable. (Either way, it's an optimization outside of the question asked.)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the `locationPoly` array appears to contain coordinates. A pair of coordinates can be considered a [**tuple**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) (ordered list). If you're using **OpenAPI 3.1** (or will be using it in the future), it has the [`prefixItems`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464633/113116) keyword to define tuples. This way you can provide separate descriptions for individual elements of the tuple (i.e., for the 1st and 2nd items of the inner arrays in your example).

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

  locationPoly:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Coordinates'
...

Coordinates:
  type: array
  prefixItems:
    # The 1st item
    - type: number
      description: Latitude
      minimum: -90
      maximum: 90
    # The 2nd item
    - type: number
      description: Longitude
      minimum: -180
      maximum: 180
  minItems: 2
  maxItems: 2
  additionalItems: false # Can be omitted if maxItems is specified
```