# Yaml variable type

Tags: variables, types, yaml, swagger

I have a variable in a yaml file with an example structure of:
[
[
1.0,
2.0
],
[
3.0,
4.0
]
]

I have defined this has

```
type:  list
items:
 type:double
```

Am I right to create this as a double even though each element is technically 2 different doubles or is another type for the items correct? Thanks

Comment: YAML is a generic data format. It doesn't know what `type` or `items` are. You are probably using some specific tool that assigns meaning to the construct you show. You have to tell us which tool this is in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @Flyx I am using swagger with python flask

Comment: Does this answer your question - [How to define a nested array in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70856802/113116)