# How do I parse an array of object in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to describe the following post parameter in swagger:

"AnyOne" =  [["971", 50.0, 70.0], ["832", 50.0, 30.0], ["134A", 50.0, 100.0]]

Comment: I guess technically it might be possible, but how do you plan to handle that parameter on java side? A list accepting both `String` and `int`? Why not make it an array of objects instead?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to write it correctly.  Please can you help me by writing an example?

Comment: @AhlamMohamed can you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I diff it like this , but my boss told me it is wrong and I now i have to figure out how.         AnyOne:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string

Comment: AnyOne:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              one:
                type: string
                description: Descrizione 
              hello:
                type: number
                description: Valore del per Garanzia
                format: double
              hello2:
                type: number
                description:

Comment: Related: [How to define a nested array in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70856802/113116)

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenAPI 3.1

Your nested array can be considered an array of [tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464633/113116). Tuples are defined using `prefixItems`. An array of tuples is defined as follows:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

type: array
items:
  type: array
  prefixItems:
    # The 1st item
    - type: string
      description: Description of the 1st item
      example: "971"
    # The 2nd item
    - type: number
      description: Description of the 2nd item
      example: 50.0
    # The 2nd item
    - type: number
      description: Description of the 3nd item
      example: 70.0

  # The total number of items in this tuple
  minItems: 3
  maxItems: 3
  additionalItems: false   # can be omitted if `maxItems` is specified
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x

The inner array can be defined as a generic [mixed-type array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38690802/113116), i.e. "can contain strings and numbers". But you cannot specifically define that the 1st element is a string and the rest are numbers. This gives us:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: array
  items:
    oneOf:
      - type: string
      - type: number
  example: ["971", 50.0, 70.0]
```

#### OpenAPI 2.0

This version does not really support mixed-type arrays like `["971", 50.0, 70.0]`. The most you can do is to use a [typeless schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116) `{}` for the `items` of the inner array, which means the inner array can contain *any* values except `null`s. You cannot specify the exact types for `items`, but you can add an `example` of an array with different item types.

```yaml
# swagger: '2.0'

type: array
items:
  type: array
  items: {}
  example: ["971", 50.0, 70.0]
```