# OpenApi 3: How do I define an array with a fixed order of custom values: all objects in the array must be in that specific order

Tags: openapi

I need to define in an OpenApi schema an Array which contains exactly three other schema objects, in a precise order.
So If I have Cat, Dog and Duck defined in my schema, I want to define something which is an array exactly like this:

```
[Dog, Duck, Dog, Cat, Cat]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to define a JSON array with concrete item definition for every index (i.e. a tuple) in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57464633/113116)

Comment: @Helen yes add this as an answer, IE this is not doable in 3.0 but needs 3.1